# How to set ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE dynamically in Robot framework

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework

Is there a way to define ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'GLOBAL' when creating tests dynamically ?

Currently I have to [define ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE in the class of my library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-library-scope), but I'd like to have it defined during the creation of the test case.

For example, I tried by adding to the imported Library - a class property:

```
suite.resource.imports.library('MyLib.py')
suite.resource.imports[-1].__class__.ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'GLOBAL'
# or with set attribute:
setattr(suite.resource.imports[-1].__class__, 'ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE', 'GLOBAL')
```

And I also tried to add a class property to the created TestCase:

```
testCase = suite.tests.create('MyTest')
testCase.__class__.ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'GLOBAL'
# or with set attribute:
setattr(testCase.__class__, 'ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE', 'GLOBAL')
```

But during test runtime, these class properties have no effect on the actual ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE.

Answer (score 1):

I've suggested an implementation to set ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE when importing custom libraries:
https://github.com/manosnoam/robotframework/commit/98f62c4b29d399cdc16b39bb61e10f835c27c48e

Once my patch is merged, you'll be able to call for example:

```
suite.resource.imports.library('YourLib.py', scope='TEST SUITE')
```

Instead of setting ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE in YourLib class:

> <strike>ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'TEST SUITE'</strike>